# Getting highest version files froma groups of similar files in a list

Tags: python, sorting

I'm looking for a way to return a list of the highest versioned files from a diverse list of filenames.  The only constant within the file name format will that they all share the same version format. A sample list would be:

```
mylist = ["File_01_v001", "File_01_v002", "File_01_v003", "File_01-test_v001", "File_01-test_v002", "File_01_v002", "File_02_v001", "File_02_v002", "File_02_v003"]
```

My return from this sample list would look like:

```
['File_01_v003', 'File_01-test_v002', 'File_02_v003']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd loop over the items, building a dictionary, to find the most recent ones.  And only the most recent are kept and then converted back down to  alist.

```
mylist = ["File_01_v001", "File_01_v002", "File_01_v003", "File_01-test_v001", "File_01-test_v002", "File_01_v002", "File_02_v001", "File_02_v002", "File_02_v003"]

def findFiles(li):
    di = {}
    for item in li:
        parts = item.split("_")
        fileName = "_".join(parts[:-1])
        version = parts[-1]
        if (fileName not in di or di[fileName] < version):
            di[fileName] = version
    return [k + "_" + di[k] for k in di]

print(findFiles(mylist))
```

Comment: I didn't consider using a dictionary.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that I made it too complicated, but it works :)

```
import re
mylist = ["File_01_v001", "File_01_v002", "File_01_v003", "File_01-test_v001", "File_01-test_v002", "File_01_v002", "File_02_v001", "File_02_v002", "File_02_v003"]
versions = {k: list(sorted([item.split('_')[2] for item in mylist if item.startswith(k)], key = lambda x: re.findall('\d+',x)[0]))[-1] for k in set(['_'.join(item.split('_')[:2]) for item in mylist])}
list_versions = ['_'.join(vers) for vers in versions.items()]
```

Comment: Not too complicated at all.  It's just all in one line, which is kind of desirable in my code ATM.  :)

Comment: Glad you like it :)